# forcing SSAS not to round, Truncate

Tags: ssas, cube

I have a named calculation in OLAP cube as a/b. SSAS rounds calculations by default. Is there any way I can force it to truncate rather than rounding.
I wanted the number as 2/3= 0.666 rather than 2/3= 0.667.

Answer (score 0):

You could try using the VBA `Fix` function in your MDX query/calculation with a multiplier to perform the truncation. For example, if you wanted to truncate the measure [Measures].[Test] to 2 decimal places, you would do the following:

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Truncated] AS
   Fix([Measures].[Test] * 1000) / 1000
SELECT [Measures].[Truncated] ON 0
FROM [Cube]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try `Round(expression [,numdecimalplaces])`, in your particular case `Round (2/3, 3)` would work.